# Undeclared identifier for [i] when creating variables dynamically

Tags: c, encryption

This following code is supposed to encrypt a sentence using the ceasers cipher, it is still WIP i haven't accounted for spaces, lower case letters etc etc.

```
int main(int argc,string argv[])
{
    int k = atoi(argv[1]);
    string value = GetString();
    int n = strlen(value);

    for(int i = 0;i<n; i++);
    {
        char temp = value[i];
        int conv = temp - (int)'A';
        int cipher = (conv + k)%26;
        char final = cipher + (int)'A'; 

        printf("%c\n",final); 
    } 
}
```

I get

```
caeser.c:15:23 use of undeclared identifier i.
```

which is on the line `char temp = value[i];`

Comment: No need to cast the character-literals to `int`, they are `int`s already. (Even if they weren't a `char` always fits into an `int` so there is no problem with conversion)

Comment: I don't think C accepts `string []` as the 2nd parameter of `main()`.

Comment: im not really sure what you mean, sorry @Kninnug

Comment: @timrau Perhaps `cs50.h` `typedef`s `string` as `char *`?

Comment: Solution: remove the `;` at the end of the `for` line.

Comment: What @Kninnug means is, there is no need to write `(int)'A'`. `int conv = temp - 'A';` works well.

Comment: I was told to use those parameters by the CS50 class and its worked for every other program except this one. @timrau

Comment: @Intent Filters Kninnug means that `char` is 1 byte, and fits into an `int` which is 4 bytes (or 8 bytes, if you have a 64-bit machine). In any case, there is *no need to cast* a `char` to an `int` because internally they are already `int`.

Comment: Thank you so much @Kninnug. Do you mind telling me why that worked?

Comment: @ Intent Filters look at his answer, he made an edit and he explains the underlying issue (what the compiler means) very well.

Comment: PS - upvoted to counter downvote. Though the question could have been  asked more appropriately, sometimes we all get caught on (syntax in this case) weird errors. Not only that, but I learned a little bit more about scopes in C today, even though that probably wasn't the intended goal of the OP!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the semicolon at the end of the `for` line:

```
for(int i = 0;i<n; i++);
```

Declaring `int i` there makes it local to the `for` block, but because of the semicolon that is an empty block.

So in the following code block (between the `{ }`) `i` is not declared because it does not belong to the `for`.

This will also fix the program not executing the body of the `for` more than once (which it would, if it compiled). If this had compiled the `for` loop would have looped until `n` but not execute anything. Then after that the code between the curly braces would have been executed with `i == n` (assumed that `i` is then visible to that code block). So your code would always execute with `temp == '\0'` (the terminating null in `value`) and always print the same cipher value.

**ENCORE**: (as explained in the comments, but here for completeness' sake)

The casts of character-literals to `int`s (`int conv = temp - (int)'A';`) are unnecessary for two reasons:

1. Contrary to what may seem intuitive character-literals are `int`s, not `char`s (this is different in C++, I believe)
2. But even if 1. weren't the case, a `char` is always smaller than an `int` and will thus always fit inside an `int` so it can safely be promoted.

Comment: Gotta love those 'syntax errors' where the compiler doesn't really give any particular hints. Although I guess it really did... sometimes I wish they just said *look for an extra semicolon on line X, dummy*. Ambiguity [on syntax errors] blows my mind sometimes.

Comment: He's actually lucky this caused an error. If it had compiled it would have caused an annoying bug where only one and the same cipher value would always be printed.

Comment: Yes this is true... sometimes declaring `int i` outside of the `for` loop is not actually a good idea - definitely one of those corner cases!

Comment: I prefer to declare my variables outside of loops, so from now on I'll never make an empty block with `;` but with empty braces: `{ }`

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is here:

```
for(int i = 0;i<n; i++);
                       ^
```

The `;` ends your *for* loop, it runs `n` times but performs no operation since the `;` just ends a *null statement*. So the `{}` afterward is just a *compound statement* with it's own scope which does not include the declaration of `i`:

```
{
  char temp = value[i]; // i does not exist here since it declared in for loop
                        // and it's scope ends with the for loop
  //...
}
```

The [C99 draft standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) tells us that what you have after the *for* is a *statement expression*, section `6.8.3` *Expression and null statements*  has the following grammar for *expression statements*:

```
expression-statement:
  expressionopt ;
```

and in paragraph *3* tells us that the empty statment is just a *null statement*:

> A null statement (consisting of just a semicolon) performs no operations.